# Apache redirect possible loop with query strings

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I don't know much about Apache rewrites and I have this set of requirements that I want to do:

```
1. http://domain.com/keyword ==> http://domain.com/index.php?c=keyword
2. http://domain.com/keyword?utm_source=affiliate ==> http://domain.com/index.php?c=keyword&utm_source=afiliate
3. Do not rewrite any request like http://domain.com/css/ http://domain.com/images/
```

I tried to learn and have been able to write a redirect like this for solving #1 and #2:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-+.,]+)\?*(.*)$ index.php?c=$1$2 [QSA]
```

This does the work for #1 and #2 in my requirements above.  However, when I try to access a URL like `http://domain.com/b` it produces following result in (PHP) `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']: c=index.php&c=b`

Also, I get a continuous loop redirect if I change (just because I was curious) the flag to [R,QSA] with absolute domain, which indicates that the rule is being processed multiple times.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a pair of `RewriteCond` to filter those paths you don't want to be rewrited, like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-+.,]+)\?*(.*)$ index.php?c=$1$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: thanks for your response. This would help in future.  But I'm afraid, my question was about not getting a clean QueryString back as my application is seeing `c=index.php&c=b` (two C values) in request

Comment: Solved it by your help.  I added a filter for /index.php and its working fine.  many thanks